# PHP --with-curl

Tags: php, curl

I need to install cURL. PHP's official website writes:

> To use PHP's cURL support you must also compile PHP --with-curl[=DIR] where DIR is the location of the directory containing the lib and include directories.

But I've seen people doing it like that:

```
<?php
// some text...
--with-curl
// some text...
?>
```

Which one should I choose?

Comment: Sometime, we see strange things...

Comment: *Compiling* PHP is different than *writing* PHP. It means that you have to build the PHP interpreter and set this flag to enable the support.

Comment: Answerers, this is a well-written question. Please explain the confusion instead of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `--with-curl` arbitrarily in the middle of your code does nothing except potentially cause syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you show does not make any sense, is not valid PHP code and the PHP interpreter will throw an error. If you want to use curl you have to [install](http://no.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php) it.

Answer (score 1):

The second option isn't valid, as others have mentioned. The only way to add modules (in this case, the one that adds curl support) is to compile PHP with those modules active. That is what `--with-php` does - tells PHP to compile with curl.

Now, the source code for some packages *do* allow you to add that to one of the compiling config files, and it often takes the same form as the command line switch. I'm not sure if PHP has that option (never needed to compile it by hand), but if it does, it's not going to be in a PHP file.

If you run a version of Linux, you also have the option of installing php-curl/php5-curl from your distribution's repository. Doing it that way saves the headache of compiling it yourself and remembering what you need to turn on and off, and handles dependency needs.

Ultimately, though, how you go about installing it or adding modules depends on your platform, skill level, and overall needs and comfort level.